# Dune version not supported

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I am trying to install google-drive-ocamlfuse from source, but the prereuiqisites got me a little confused. I am experiencing this error:

```
[bf@localhost google-drive-ocamlfuse]$ dune build @install
File "/home/bf/.opam/default/lib/gapi-ocaml/dune-package", line 1, characters 11-15:
1 | (lang dune 1.11)
               ^^^^
Error: Version 1.11 of dune is not supported.
Supported versions:
- 0.0
- 1.0 to 1.7
```

I have dune version 1.7 installed:

```
[bf@localhost google-drive-ocamlfuse]$ dune --version
%%VERSION%%
[bf@localhost google-drive-ocamlfuse]$ sudo dnf install dune
[sudo] password for bf: 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:48:24 ago on Wed 21 Aug 2019 15:57:42 CEST.
Package ocaml-dune-1.7.3-1.fc29.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

But apparently, gapi-ocaml needs dune 1.11, or am I completely mistaken? I have no experience with OCaml or dune or all the other tools...

How can I get this installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use your distribution's version of `dune`. Instead, get it via `opam`:

```
dnf remove dune
opam install dune
```