# Error: Version 1.11 of dune is not supported

Tags: macos, ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I want to test this project: https://github.com/nt591/monkey-ocaml on my Mac. After downloading the project, `dune runtest` returned the following error:

```
$ dune runtest
File "dune-project", line 1, characters 11-15:
1 | (lang dune 1.11)
               ^^^^
Error: Version 1.11 of dune is not supported.
Supported versions:
- 0.0
- 1.0 to 1.6
```

Then, I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661144/702977), but it returned this:

```
$ dnf remove dune
-bash: dnf: command not found
```

Do I have to install `dnf`? Could anyone help?

Comment: How did you install `dune`? `dnf` is what was used to install it in the question you reference, so that's what needs to be used to remove it as well.

Comment: I don't remember how I installed dune. `dune --version` returned `1.6.3`.

Comment: I don't think anyone else will be able to remember it for you either, or know which package managers you might have installed, so I guess you'll just have to try. `brew` seems a likely culprit on macOS, or maybe you've installed it with `opam` and just have to update. `which dune` might help you figure it out.

Comment: `which dune` returned `/Users/SoftTimur/.opam/system/bin/dune`.

Comment: `opam update && opam upgrade` should fix it then.

Comment: Unless you have an old version of `opam`, which you probably do, so maybe upgrade that too.

Comment: Just `opam update && opam upgrade` and then `opam install alcotest fmt` solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments, but in case anyone else stumbles across this, `dune` was installed with `opam` but out of date, so the fix was a simple `opam update && opam upgrade`.

If `dune` is installed in some other way, it's strongly recommended that you uninstall that instance and install it using `opam´ instead.